# 心電. What do we translate this?

Tags: meaning

Full text: 帯域通過特性によってセンスアンプに入った信号から心電位が検出される。

My issue: 心電. What do we translate this? Is it Heart potential or Electrocardiographic potential?

My understanding: The heart potential/electrocardiographic potential is detected from the signal entering the sense amplifier due to the bandpass characteristic.

Comment: Harpreet, thank you for your consistently good questions. I enjoy them very much.

Comment: Just curious: is the heart potential different from the electrocardiographic potential?

Comment: @Yosh heart potentialという用語はあるんでしょうか（検索してもミクロな膜電位の話しか出てきません）

Comment: @Ragaroni Sure, I will continue asking questions.

Comment: @Yosh The kanji for both were different. electrocardiography kanji is 心電図. This is different from my text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not 心電 + 位 but 心 (heart; cardio-) + [電位](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%9B%BB%E4%BD%8D) ([electric potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential)). 心電位 is "electric potential of the heart". Or you can simply use "electric potential" when there is enough context (i.e., when everyone understands this article is about ECG).

Comment: Thank you for your help.